# Absolute positioning within a relatively positioned element refuses to work

Tags: css

I'm probably missing something blatant here, but this is driving me nuts.

Page in question is the [home page of this test site](http://searchanddevelop.ca/adv/).

- header id is relatively positioned and I'm trying to absolutely position elements within it (photos of two people and text next to those photos, #bodyad1 and #bodyad2).
- Problem is, they refuse to work and end up being absolutely positioned *outside* of #header, relative to the body.

Odd thing is I've already positioned another element absolutely inside the header and it works (photo of a ribbon). However when I insert the other two elements the header just breaks: all the header content moves to the bottom of the page.

Any thoughts?

```
<div id="bodyad1">
    <img src="images/person1.png" alt="">
    <div id="bodyad1-text">
        <h3>—Featured Story—</h3>
        <p>John Smith</p>
        <h2>Toronto Criminal Lawyer</h2>
</div>

<div id="bodyad2">
    <img src="images/person2.png" alt="">
    <div id="bodyad2-text">
        <h3>—Featured Story—</h3>
        <p>John Smith</p>
        <h2>Toronto Criminal Lawyer</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="adlogo">
    <img src="images/advocatedaily-logo.png" alt="Advocate Daily dot com Logo">
    <h2>Ontario's Legal News</h2>
</div>
 <div id="adsash"></div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS (yes, I know I could make my styles more concise)

```
/*header*/
#header {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9e0505;
  position: relative;
}
/*   Featured Lawyer Body Shots   */

#bodyad1 {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    height: 94px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 60px;
}

#bodyad2 {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    height: 94px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 60px;

}

#bodyad1 img{
    float:right;
    display:block;
}

#bodyad1-text {
    height:94px;
    float:right;
}

#bodyad1-text  h3 {
    font: italic 10px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    text-align: right;
}

#bodyad1-text  p {
    font: normal bold 11px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #cd1713;
    text-align: right;
}

#bodyad1-text  h2 {
    font: normal bold 11px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    text-align: right;
}

#bodyad2 img {
    float:left;
    display:block;
}

#bodyad2-text {
    height: 94px;
    float: left;
}

#bodyad2-text  h3 {
    font: italic 10px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    text-align: left;
}

#bodyad2-text  p {
    font: normal bold 11px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #cd1713;
    text-align: left;
}

#bodyad2-text  h2 {
    font: normal bold 11px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any styles for the header, but I don't see `position: relative` in any of the code you posted

Comment: When I view the link you've given and inspect the page all the page content is within the `<div id="header">` which I'm sure is not what you want... would lead me to believe you have a missing close `</div>` tag somewhere.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: sorry, I only pasted the styles from the bottom of my sheet. Declared the header id earlier (updated my original post).

Comment: @pebbl: Thanks, all my tags should be closed but I may have missed something. Checking it out now.

Comment: Try validating your html to spot the missing tags.  http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsearchanddevelop.ca%2Fadv%2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a closing div tag, but I made it look like I had indeed closed it due to my indentation style.

Pretty ridiculous thing to post about. Carry on.

Thank you @pebbl.

Comment: Atleast you found it for yourself!!